# Which one of the following flows is considered good practice?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume I have code which handle two flows:

```
if flow1:
    do step 1
    do step 2
    do step 3

if flow 2:
    do step 1
    do step 2
    do step 3
    do step 4
    do step 5
```

From my perspective, there are three approaches to handle these:

**approach 1**

```
def get_flow_type():

def do_flow_wrapper():
    if flow_type = 1:
        do_flow1()

    elif flow_type = 2:
        do_flow2()

def do_flow1()
    do step 1
    do step 2
    do step 3

def do_flow2()
    do step 1
    do step 2
    do step 3
    do step 4
    do step 5
```

**approach 2**

```
def get_flow_type():

def do_flow_wrapper():
    do step 1
    do step 2
    do step 3

    if flow_type = 2:
        do step 4
        do step 5
```

**approach 3**

```
def get_flow_type():

def do_flow_wrapper():
    if flow_type = 1:
        do_flow1()

    elif flow_type = 2:
        do_flow2()

def do_first_three_steps()

def do_flow1()
    do_first_three_steps()

def do_flow2()
    do_first_three_steps()
    do step 4
    do step 5
```

Approach #1 causes code duplication (steps 1, 2 and 3) are shown twice.

Approach #2 seems like the correct approach. However, the function does two things, and I find this approach breaking the rule of "function must do just 1 thing" (which should be simply reflected in the function name).

Approach 3 seems like combining approaches #1 and #2 while avoiding the code duplication by using a helper function.

**So is approach 3 considered the best in terms of avoiding code duplication while keeping the code easy to debug (when function do much more than one thing i.e "if x do 1 and if y do 2" it makes debugging code harder)?**

Thanks,

Qwerty

Comment: Use aproach 2, it is more clear

Comment: I think [this Hot Network Question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302198/two-structs-with-the-same-members-but-different-naming-is-it-a-good-idea) has some coherence with your question and may be useful. It is about `struct`s, but touches the same question - if we should abstract out every possible thing or allow some duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely the approach 3 is better than other approaches from the perspective of code redundancy, code-maintainence, code reusability and unit-testing.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a BETTER approach than approach 3? is approach 3 is considered best practice in this SPECIFIC CASE?

Comment: It still depends on your problem and domain. But approach 3 virtually doesn't have any problem, considering good programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose approach #3 is the good one, but you should document this decision in code.

Try to think of someone who will need to change some of the 1..3 steps specifically for flow_1 or flow_2 -- how it will be easy for him to understand your today decision against code duplication in flow_1 and flow_2.

Should he be allowed to extract those 1..3 steps into flow_1 and flow_2 and change them in one of that flows?

Comment: Listen, my post deals with the question of how to handle two flows, when both flows have some (but not ALL) common steps. So steps 1-3 are common for BOTH flows. Asking "what will happen if these steps are not common" is not relevant for this post.

Comment: What would happen if someone will need to write another programm? That's what you're asking. So the answer is clear: They will write another programm.

Comment: Alex S, thanks for backing my up! :-)